# Est-ce une erreur ou un règle que je ne sais pas "Je ne l’entends que dans mon oreille gauche."-article masculin avec feminin substantif

Tags: grammaire, genre, déterminants

De *L'embrasement* par Suzanne Collins:

> Je ne l’entends que dans ***mon oreille*** gauche.

Est-ce que le déterminant possessif masculin est utilisé à cause de la voyelle O ou est-ce simplement une erreur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C'est effectivement à cause de la voyelle.
Les exemples sont nombreux, on peut citer par exemple *ma fille* et ***mon*** autre fille, mon automobile, etc.

Comment: voir à ce sujet cette page avec des compléments intéressants : https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic31601-mon-ton-son-devant-un-substantif-feminin.html

Comment: J'ai peut-être appris la règle et l'ai oublié

Comment: et l'ai oublié**e** ;)